# Import interval column from teradata into SQL Server

Tags: type-conversion, sql-server-2014, teradata, linked-server

I am trying to import a table from Teradata into SQL Server, using a linked server. This table has a column with data type interval time to minute that is causing the issue. The value in the column is  0:18.

In SQL Server, I do something like this :

```
select <mycol>
into <SQLTable>
from openquery(<TERADATADB>,
               'select *
                from <TDBD>.<TDTable>') T
```

I get a result which is a `binary(6)` and the value is 0x000000000000 which corresponds to ASCII 0.

I would expect to have 0x303A31380000 which is the binary equivalent of '0:18' as returned in the cast below run in SQL Server.

```
select cast('0:18' as binary(6))
```

Do you have any idea why this issue? Should I reinstall my SQL Server?

I have a SQL Server 2014 Express installed on my Surface Pro, Windows 10, 64 bit.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the type of the column you are inserting into? SQL Server supports INTERVAL types, so I would assume it would map. Your binary `0x303A31380000` is just the binary of the varchar `0:18` so I would suspect you would see something besides that when it comes through as it's not VARCHAR on the Teradata side.

Comment: What datatype do you want to use to store an Interval in SQL Server? Try ´CAST(col AS Varchar(10))`

Comment: @JNevill I did a select into (so the table does not exist, it is created by the SELECT statement). So I was expecting to get the INTERVAL type by default. Or else the binary 0x303A31380000. But what I get is 0x000000000000 !

Comment: @dnoeth If I do a cast it works but I do not understand why the interval cannot be converted correctly via the linked server. And also I asked a colleague who has the same configuration than me to run the same code and he got the binary value 0x303A31380000. So I don't understand why I don't get the same.

Comment: Which SQL Server release supports an INTERVAL data type? Your binary value is the value returned for the *string* `0:18  `.

Comment: @dnoeth Perhaps the interval data type in sql server is newer (2017). [Found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/interval-data-types?view=sql-server-2017). It is very interesting that it is casting the interval as a string and then storing that from the linked server on the coworker's computer. Perhaps when all else fails, that's the behavior for an unknown field type of a linked table.

Comment: @JNevill: The link claims that ODBC supports it, but it's definitely not a SQL Server data type :-)

Comment: So maybe my version of SQL Server does not support interval which is why I have a binary conversion. But why is the binary value I get is wrong (0x000000000000) and my coworker gets the right one (0x303A31380000) ?